Determine finbuckle tenant in ASP.NET Core web app without http request
I'm using Finbuckle for multitenancy support in ASP.NET Core web application. The app uses the host strategy to identify the tenant.
Now, I want to integrate MassTransit over RabbitMQ for handling messages. However, when app receives a MassTransit message, there isn't an HTTP request to identify the tenant, so the multitenant DbContext can't be instantiated. App uses multiple MassTransit buses and every bus uses its own RabbitMQ vhost.
I can implement Finbuckle custom strategy but how can I make this strategy use MassTransit data in order to determine tenant?

How do you use RabbitMQ? Do you have a queue per tenant? Pass the tenant as part of the message? so the multitenant DbContext can't be instantiated. that's wrong. EF Core isn't tied to HttpContext in any way. If you pass the TenantID as a parameter during construction, you can pass whatever you pull from the RabbitMQ message as well. If you try to access HttpContext from inside DbContext, you have a critical bug. At the very least you should inject a service that retrieves the TenantID so you can change it with another implementation

I have RabbitMQ vhost per tenant. I'm using Finbuckle multitenant library and its host strategy to resolve tenant. Finbuckle also supports EF.Core.

Don't expect people to know what Finbuckle is. And EF Core doesn't care about Finbuckle. If you have a different host per tenant, you already know who the tenant is when you receive a message. If Finbuckle works with "static" settings (eg from configuration or DI) or allows making a call to determine the tenant, it should work with the tenant that corresponds to the host you connect to.

I know what both Finbuckle is, and MassTransit, and you're basically screwed if you're using a vhost per tenant. A future version of MassTransit is adding multitenant support, that will also eliminate the need for Finbuckle (it's similar primitives).
